# Effect of Background Radiation on a Transmitted Signal

Tags: radiation, signal-processing

I'm coding a basic simulation of using error correcting codes to transmit data from a satellite back to earth. I'm not sure what to set the "noise level" to. Let's say a satellite orbiting Mars transmits a signal which contains 128 bits, approximately how many of those bits would be changed by the time the signal reaches earth?

This is just for fun so I don't need any references, just an approximation, however it would still be interesting if someone could point me to a reliable source :)

Update: I'm basing this on Mariner 9, I managed to find that the transmissions were at 20 watts, using the S-Band, which I think is somewhere around 2.2 ghz

Comment: I would say that depends on the strength of the signal transmitted and the frequency of the transmission... Could you update with these details?

Comment: I'm basing this on Mariner 9, the specs for the radio are 20 watts, S-Band (2-4ghz?)

Comment: Maybe you can consider a thermal noise of space, from wikipedia I can see that the temperature is about 30 - 150 K. For a 300K the noise density is -174 dBm/Hz